# Windows 10 doesn't show recent files on right click icon in taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I'm on Windows 10 1803, this happened recently- probably after a Windows update:

[image]

The right click menu doesn't show the recent opened files!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

bro!
I m Brasilian so I am using a portuguese version but I will try to help you as better as I can. To fix it, you need to Go to settings > personalize > and click on "start".
Enable the option "show itens opened recently in shortcut lists in Start or Tool bars" or something like that.
Close the window.
Finish!!
:D